# Did this artist take some licence with the Royal Albert Bridge - or has its appearance changed?

Tags: bridges

Here is how this artist rendered [Brunel's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isambard_Kingdom_Brunel) [Saltash Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Albert_Bridge):

[image]

Here is how it appears today.

[image]

Did the appearance change, or was some artistic licence taken in the painting?

My question is: **Did this artist take some licence with the Royal Albert Bridge - or has its appearance changed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably artistic interpretation. #i see the differences you are alluding  to but they don't look like things you could reasonably alter in a structure.

The artist's rendering looks like an engraving or etching and as such the final image would have gone through several stages probably starting with a sketch in the field in pencil or watercolours before being worked up into a more detailed composition and then being adapted by the engraver.

At each stage there would have been some degree of interpretation to produce a pleasing composition as well as practical limitations imposed by the processes used. It is certainly not uncommon for landscape artists to idealise scenes a bit and engravers would need to interpret the image to convert it into a printable grey-scale format.

Answer (score 1):

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Royal_albert_bridge_hist.jpg

The picture from when the original was being jacked into place shows the lens closed at each end.

The engraving would have been from before the bridge was constructed -- perhaps while the railway corporation was trying to raise money.